# como obtener respuesta JSON en mi proyecto de Android?

Tags: java, android, json

Estoy intentando obtener los datos que obtengo a partir de un web service. Este es el resultado de json que tengo:

**[{"masculino":"2"},{"femenino":"1"},{"otros":"0"},{"total_alumnos":"3"}]**

Quisiera saber que error tengo al manipular esos datos porque no responde el servicio web.
Este es el código

```
public void mostrarDatos() {
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_consulta_sexos_alumnos, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("VOLLEY", response);
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    femenino = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("masculino");
                    masculino = jsonArray.getJSONObject(1).getString("femenino");
                    otros = jsonArray.getJSONObject(2).getString("otros");
                    total_alumnos = jsonArray.getJSONObject(3).getString("total_alumnos");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("entraerror", response);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

Otros metodos que tengo en la clase:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reportes, container, false);
    pieChart=view.findViewById(R.id.pieChartEdadAlumnos);
    barChart=view.findViewById(R.id.barChartInasistencias);
    mostrarDatos();
    crearGraficoPastel();
    return view;
}

private void crearGraficoPastel() {
    Description description = new Description();
    description.setText("grafico de pastel");
    description.setTextSize(15);
    pieChart.setDescription(description);
    final ArrayList<PieEntry> pieEntries=new ArrayList<>();
    int mas_nro =Integer.parseInt(masculino);
    int fem_nro = Integer.parseInt(femenino);

    pieEntries.add(new PieEntry(fem_nro,3));
    pieEntries.add(new PieEntry(mas_nro,8));

    PieDataSet pieDataSet=new PieDataSet(pieEntries,"leyenda");
    pieDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

    PieData pieData= new PieData(pieDataSet);
    pieChart.setData(pieData);
}
```

Las busqueda en el Log cat para ver si entraba a los metodos onResponse o onErrorResponse fueron nulas.

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Agrego nuevo error a partir de las sugerencias:

```
 2021-06-02 21:30:30.095 4168-4168/com.example.gimnasio_unne E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.gimnasio_unne, PID: 4168
    androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.gimnasio_unne.view.fragments.FragmentReportes: calling Fragment constructor caused an exception
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:566)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:57)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate(FragmentManager.java:390)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.instantiateFragment(FragmentNavigator.java:132)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:162)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:58)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:1049)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:935)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:868)
        at androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(NavigationUI.java:87)
        at androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI$3.onNavigationItemSelected(NavigationUI.java:443)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:215)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:840)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:991)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:416)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at
```

Actualizo: ya pude solucionar. MIL GRACIAS A TODOS

```
2021-06-02 22:04:30.600 6252-6252/com.example.gimnasio_unne D/VOLLEY: [{"masculino":"2"},{"femenino":"1"},{"otros":"0"},{"total_alumnos":"3"}]
```

Saludos!

Comment: ¿Muestra algún mensaje de error?

Comment: Al ejecutar cae la aplicación. Y cuando ejecuto con el log no va al OnResponse va a Response.ErrorListener(). JSON manejo maso, la sintaxis de jsonArray.getJSONObject(0) seria correcta para la respuesta que tengo desde el web service?

Comment: No sé a qué te refieres al decir *cuando ejecuto con el log*. Si el servidor responde únicamente el contenido que indicas la lectura al estilo `jsonArray.getJSONObject(0)` es correcta. Significa en este caso obtener el primer objeto JSON que hay dentro del `JSONArray`. Si tienes problemas en esa parte comenta todo ese bloque de código y haz un `Log.d` de `response` para verificar si la petición está comunicando con el servidor realmente y si está recibiendo algo. Y si dices que va a listener de error pues lo mismo, haz un `Log.d` del mensaje de error y dinos cuál es.

Comment: No podemos ayudarte con tan poca información. El código que muestras no ayuda y la captura que subiste está incompleta. Edita la pregunta y añade toda la información  que pueda ser relevante, preferentemente como código porque hay usuario que no pueden ver las imagenes.

Comment: Agregue un Log.d dentro de onResponse y onErrorResponse pero no entra a ninguno. Y aparentemente el flujo del codigo es correcto.

Comment: El código tiene que entrar a alguna parte. ¿Seguro que sabes revisar el Log cat? Debe mostrarte al menos el tag que has puesto a la izquierda.

Comment: ¿Qué librería usas para procesar el resultado JSON?

Comment: @A.Cedano Si, coloco el TAG VOLLEY y entraerror pero marca en rojo ambos.

Comment: @AriadnaCortéz volley uso. Ya realicé otras consultas y no he tenido ningun problema. No se si el problema es del lado del servidor

Comment: @AriadnaCortéz no está usando librerias para la deserialización, los métodos que se ven son nativos. De todos modos no se le puede ayudar si no muestra el logcat

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con *entra error* y con *marca en rojo ambos*? Si no explicas con claridad la situación es complicado poder ayudarte. ¿Qué error marca? ¿Qué es lo que marca en rojo? ¿Qué dice al marcar en rojo?

Comment: @A.Cedano El resultado de la búsqueda del TAG marca en rojo, porque no encontró resultados. Ahi adjunto imagen

Comment: Entiendo. Pero ahí se ve que está ocurriendo una Excepción en tu código, en `FragmentReportes`. Debes resolver ese problema o de lo contrario nada va a funcionar.

Comment: Si ocurre esa excepcion porque obtiene un null de la variable "masculino" y "femenino" que son los datos que quiero obtener del servicio web, del cual no obtengo respuesta.

Comment: No, la excepcion ocurre porque trataste de convertir en `int` una `String` que no tenía formato de número y eso pasó en la función `crearGraficoPastel`. Y nunca podremos ayudarte a menos que muestres esa función.

Comment: No puede ser. Si entreara en esa parte, esto se vería: `Log.d("VOLLEY", response);` Lee bien el mensaje, dice que **intentas convertir a entero una variable llamada `s` pero dicha variable es nula o algo así...**. Eso no tiene nada que ver con lo de masculino o femenino. Haz click en las partes en azul irá llevando al lugar donde empieza a originarse la Excepción.

Comment: `int mas_nro =Integer.parseInt(masculino);` aquí comienza tu excepción o ¿es lo que tú crees?

Comment: puedes agregar más líneas del stack trace?

Comment: GRACIAS A TODOS POR SU AYUDA! ya pude solucionar. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

El error ocurre porque intentas crear el gráfico antes de que se complete la consulta y por lo tanto las propiedades son nulas.
Lo que debes hacer es llamar el método `crearGraficoPastel()` despues de haber recibido la respuesta del servidor. Es decir, llamarlo en el `onResponse` en vez de en el `onCreateView`

```
public void mostrarDatos() {
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_consulta_sexos_alumnos, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("VOLLEY", response);
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    femenino = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("masculino");
                    masculino = jsonArray.getJSONObject(1).getString("femenino");
                    otros = jsonArray.getJSONObject(2).getString("otros");
                    total_alumnos = jsonArray.getJSONObject(3).getString("total_alumnos");
                    crearGraficoPastel();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("entraerror", response);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

Comment: Ahi aplique esta sugerencia, el problema es que no entra al onResponse.

Comment: Eliminaste la llamada `crearGraficoPastel()`  del `onCreateView`?

Comment: Si, si lo eliminé..

Comment: Ok, al menos ahora te debe mostrar otro error. Agregalo en la pregunta

Comment: Ya pude solucionar, ya recibi respuesta del servidor. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!